# I have a keyboard that has some keys that do nothing on my Mac in OS X, is there any way to fix this?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

This is the keyboard, it's made by Lenovo for media centers: [Link](http://www.thinkpads.com/2010/03/15/user-review-lenovo-multimedia-remote-with-keyboard/) | [Direct link to picture](http://www.thinkpads.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/lenovo_multimedia_keyboard_remote_user-review-fingerprints.jpg)

I've got it connected to my Mac Mini running 10.6.

A few of the keys on the keyboard don't seem to do anything at all, notably the big orange button in the upper-left, and the media stop button. Other than that, it works well.

Is there any way for me to remap these keys, especially given that I don't even know the name of the big orange key?

Comment: You can use xev on the console to find out if keyboard signals are being registered. Being a linux user, I can't help you much beyond that with osx specific ways of binding the keys, but I'm sure it's possible if the signals are being registered.

Comment: @SBI Thanks, but unfortunately, same result as when I tried Lauri's suggestion. Ordinary keyboard and mouse events are captured, but none of the special key like play, stop, or orange are captured by xev.

Answer (score 2):

Using KeyRemap4MacBook, you could open EventViewer.app and see if the keys are associated with any values like KeyCode::PC_APPLICATION or KeyCode::F18. If they are, you can remap them in [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

If some key combinations are captured by the OS, you can use the [debug mode](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html.en#debugmode):

```
$ sudo sysctl -w keyremap4macbook.debug=1
$ tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep KeyRemap
Apr 19 20:50:44 Lauris-iMac kernel[0]: KeyRemap4MacBook --Debug-- KeyboardEventCallback [ caught]: eventType 11, flags 0x80000000, key   46, kbdType  40, repeat = 0
Apr 19 20:50:44 Lauris-iMac kernel[0]: KeyRemap4MacBook --Debug-- KeyboardEventCallback [sending]: eventType 11, flags 0x00000000, key   46, kbdType  40, repeat = 0
^C
$ sudo sysctl -w keyremap4macbook.debug=0
```

Comment: Thanks! So I tried it out, and oddly enough, the app works and registers and displays for all pressed regular keyboard keys. However, the EventViewer doesn't seem to be capturing any of the special media keys at all. For example, the play button on my remote definitely works with OS X, because when it is pressed, it launches iTunes. However, even when EventViewer is open, pressing play launches iTunes instead of displaying anything in EventViewer. Similarly, neither the orange or stop button registers. Any ideas on what's going on or next steps?

Comment: I edited the answer. In the example above key 46 is tab (0x30). Some buttons or keys might not be sent to OS X at all.

Comment: The updated instructions worked, with the media buttons now displaying in the log, but unfortunately, nothing appeared at all for the orange or stop buttons, so I'm guessing I'm probably out of luck. I assume these keys are somehow being discarded by the OS X keyboard drivers? In Windows, it functions simply as a generic USB keyboard, it seems really strange that the stop button wouldn't even by making it to OS X.

Comment: Usually, only keys that have a scancode or keycode will show up. You can check if keys have anything the kernel can work with by checking dmesg for something along the lines of "unknown key pressed" ("dmesg | grep -i unknown" should do the job). If nothing shows up, I guess you're out of luck as nothing gets through to the kernel.